# #VALUE error with Excel VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel spreadsheet I have two columns.

- A contains strings with the values 'Yes', 'No' or 'Maybe'.
- B contains strings with a year in.

I need a function to determine the number of occurrences of a year in column B, where the equivalent value in column A is 'Yes'.

I currently have the following code:

```
Function CountIfYearAndValue(Rng As Range, YNM As String, Year As String) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If (StrComp(Abs(c.Value), Year, vbTextCompare) = 0) And (StrComp(Cells(c.Row, A), YMN, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then count = count + 1
    Next

    CountIfYearAndValue = count
End Function
```

The idea of this code is that we iterate through every cell in the range given (a range on column B) and check if the year is equal to the `Year` parameter. And if the equivalent cell on column A is equal to the `YNM` parameter we increment the `count` variable.

For some reason this code does not work when I use the following parameter:

```
=CountIfYearAndValue('Years'!B1:B7,"Yes","Year 7")
```

It just does the `#VALUE` error and refuses to display any outcome.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** All of the values in both cells are on of an unformatted datatype ('General') and no cells are blank.

Comment: Kezz101, @mehow is absolutely right it's better to use "COUNTIF". But, if you're interesing why your solution doesn't work - it's because of  1) `Cells(c.Row, A)`. You should add quotes to `A` : `Cells(c.Row, "A")` and 2) in functions parameters you are using `YNM As String`, but in code you are using `StrComp(Cells(c.Row, A), YMN, vbTextCompare)`. Note, there is `YMN` and `YNM`. I suggest you to use `Option Explicit` to avoid such kind of errors

Comment: @simoco Thanks for the response! I have now used the `COUNTIF` function, but I'm interested to see why it still doesn't work. I implemented your changes and it still doesn't work with the same `#VALUE` error.

Comment: can't figured it out, because I haven't seen your updated code, but with this changes your function works for me

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Oh well, COUNTIFS works fine anyway!

Comment: thanks @simoco I have added those you've pointed out and a few more, good job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are reinventing the wheel... There already is a built in function (*advantage: being much faster than a UDF*) that does **exactly** what you are after. It is called [**`COUNTIFS()`**](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php)

All `YES`es for `Year 7` in rows 1 to 10.

`=COUNTIFS(B1:B10, "Year 7",A1:A10, "Yes")`

---

I just had a quick look at your code and I think there are possibly a few reasons why your original code is not working as expected.

- `YNM` is a valid column name therefore it should not be used as a variable name. You should avoid naming your variables like that - give it a more meaningful name
- `YNM` != `YMN` as you had it in your code (*see function definition and then the misspelled version in the `StrComp()` function*)
- `Year` is a valid VBA built in function, therefore once again you should avoid using it as a variable name as you're exposing yourself to a naming collision.
- Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. This requires you to `Dim`ension all you variables. It's always recommended for many many reasons.
- `rng` variable is of `Range` type therefore you do not need to explicitly add the `.Cells` property to it. Even though it may help in some cases - at a bit more advanced level you may face some runtime type compatibility issues. ( *runtime may convert your `rng` Range variable to a 2D array etc* )
- Added an explicit conversion in the second `StrComp()` function around the `c.Offset(0, -1)` as you don't want the runtime to (*rare but still possible*) convert your `Yes` to a `Boolean` data type. Explicit conversion to a `String` just gives you that *extra protection* ;p (lol)

therefore, something like this returns the correct value

```
Function CountIfYearAndValue(rng As Range, choice As String, myYear As String) As Long
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng
        If (StrComp(c, myYear, vbTextCompare) = 0) And (StrComp(CStr(c.Offset(0, -1)), choice, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next c

    CountIfYearAndValue = count
End Function
```

Right, I hope this helps you understand bits and pieces :) any questions please leave a comment

Comment: This works perfectly, but still throws a `#VALUE` error when it encounters empty cells. Anyway to fix this other than filling in the empty cells?

Comment: @Kezz101, are you using ranges with the same rows count (e.g. `B1:B10` and `A1:A10` has the same rows count)?

Comment: @Kezz101 hey I have edited my answer with some extra explanations for you. If you're happy with it consider accepting it, cheers